# Default Constructor overloading

Tags: java, date, constructor, overloading

Probably a really stupid question but I cant get the default constructor work with date. This is all I have left to do. Thank you and if you could please explain why you it initialized it that way also would be wonderful. THank YOU!

```
    private String first;
 private String last;
 private double sales;
 private  Date date; 

 public SalesAgent(){
   this("", "", 0, (my problem lays here) );
 }
 public SalesAgent(String first, String last, double sales, Date date){
   setDate(date);
   setFirst(first);
   setLast(last);
   setSales(sales);
 }
```

Comment: You're trying to call your constructor with 3 parameters when it takes 4. Actually, that looks like a compilation error because of the last comma.

Comment: I know that but how do Initialize the Date date in the default constructor thank you

Comment: `new Date()` not what you wanted?

Comment: You pass it a reference to a new `Date` object, or `null`. What that default value is, is something we can't answer for you.

Comment: Consider reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a no-arg constructor that acts as a pass-through to another constructor that sets fields, then the preferred convention is to set the fields directly instead of going through the setter.

```
public SalesAgent() {
    // Seems more desirable to instantiate a new Date than leave it null
    this("", "", 0, new Date());
}
```

Without the setter:

```
 public SalesAgent(String first, String last, double sales, Date date) {
     this.first = first;
     this.last = last;
     this.sales = sales;
     this.date = date;
 }
```

Comment: Pet peeve: It's not a default constructor if it's provided in the source. It's a parameter-less or no-arg constructor.